# My step counter service doesn't appear to be sending a signal?

Tags: java, android

I have wrote a basic step counter program but the counter itself doesn't change when testing it, I have tried through a usb connection and a device over wifi and still no luck.
The issue seems to be in the service not sending a signal.

This is my java code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    Sensor myStepCounter;
    SensorManager sensorMan;
    TextView stepsNumber;
    boolean appRunning = false;
    int stepsNum =0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stepsNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stepsNumber);
        sensorMan = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if(sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null){
            myStepCounter = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
            appRunning = true;
        }else{
            stepsNumber.setText("Counter Missing");
            appRunning = false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null)
            sensorMan.registerListener(this, myStepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null)
            sensorMan.unregisterListener(this, myStepCounter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor == myStepCounter){
                stepsNum = (int) sensorEvent.values[0];
                stepsNumber.setText(String.valueOf(stepsNum));
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

}
```

And this is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.etivity5">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Etivity5">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: In the code you have provided there is an activity and not a service. Have you debugged your code to see what happens?

Comment: I have ran a debugger and received the following error `E/SensorManager: unregisterListenerImpl sensorName:pedometer  Non-wakeup,isWakeUpSensor:false,callingApp: com.example.etivity5,callingPid:16175,callingUid:10448` I'm not sure how to fix this error, I know the Listener must not be registered but I don't know how to fix it.